# jQuery 'on' parent selector reuse

Tags: jquery, caching, jquery-selectors

for I want to cache my jQuery selectors to use later on.

To do so, I can do:

```
var parent = $('#parent');

$('.arrow', parent).click(function(){});
```

This code will not work if my `#parent` or `#parent .arrow` is dynamic element. For that I need to use `.on()`

```
$(document).on('click', '#dynamicParent .arrow', function(){});
```

But now I don't have cached selector. How can I cache selector and later use it inside `.on()` event binding?

Something like

```
$(document).on('click', '.arrow', dynamicParet, function(){})
```

?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if only the `.arrow` is dynamic you can use

```
var $parent = $('#parent');
$parent.on('click', '.arrow', function () {});
```

if the parent is dynamic you can't cache it by definition

Answer (score 0):

Delegated event handlers cannot use caching, as the selector is applied *at event time*, but they do not require caching anyway as they are quite efficient. Unless you can click 50,000 times a second you are worrying about the wrong thing :)

Just use delegated your event handlers. The best thing you can do to improve efficiency (a little) is to bind the delegated event handler to the nearest non-dynamic element you can.

e.g. if `#dynamicParent` is not dynamic itself:

```
$('#dynamicParent').on('click', '.arrow', function(){});
```